# Oracle Check constraint that compares dates column from another table

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

I want to add a check constraint to a table that needs comparison of a column to another table.

This is the select statement

```
select * from a join b
on a.id = b.id
where a.valid_to <= b.end_date;
```

and the rows that violates this rule if a.valid_to > b.end_date then that should not be entered into the db.

How can I create this check contraint?

If I have to create a function with this select statement, please help with the syntax.
TIA!

Comment: you cannot do that in a check constraint.  You need to add a trigger.

Comment: can you please give me trigger syntax to prevent transactions that satisfies "select statement select * from a join b on a.id = b.id where a.valid_to > b.end_date"

Comment: SO is not a tutoring site.  There are plenty examples on the internet.  Please do some basic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger, as you were told.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table test_a
  2  (id       number,
  3   valid_to date);

Table created.

SQL> create table test_b
  2  (id       number,
  3   end_date date);

Table created.
```

Trigger on table `test_a`:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_ta
  2    before insert or update on test_a
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_num number;
  6  begin
  7    select 1
  8      into l_num
  9      from test_b b
 10      where b.id = :new.id
 11        and :new.valid_to <= b.end_date
 12        and rownum = 1;
 13  exception
 14    when no_data_found then
 15      raise_application_error(-20000, 'VALID_TO must be lower then its END_DATE (or END_DATE does not exist)');
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: this a reference record:

```
SQL> insert into test_b (id, end_date) values (1, date '2022-06-25');

1 row created.
```

Inserting ID that doesn't exist in `test_b`:

```
SQL> insert into test_a (id, valid_to) values (2, date '2022-05-15');
insert into test_a (id, valid_to) values (2, date '2022-05-15')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: VALID_TO must be lower then its END_DATE (or END_DATE does not
exist)
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TA", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TA'
```

Inserting ID that exists, but with an invalid date value:

```
SQL> insert into test_a (id, valid_to) values (1, date '2022-10-15');
insert into test_a (id, valid_to) values (1, date '2022-10-15')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: VALID_TO must be lower then its END_DATE (or END_DATE does not
exist)
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TA", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TA'
```

This is OK: ID exists, `valid_to` is lower than appropriate `end_date`:

```
SQL> insert into test_a (id, valid_to) values (1, date '2022-04-11');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: You might want to change the `select 1` to `select count(1)` in case there are multiple rows in `test_b` that match the criteria.

Comment: I might, but I don't want to, @eaolson :) Only one is enough to raise an error, I don't really care how many rows there are.

Comment: @littlefoot : thank you!! this worked perfectly fine for my scenario. I am new to triggers and this was very helpful